# lightning:inputField AccountId Field Label

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-community

I'm trying to create Opportunity using `lightning:recordEditForm`, the form contains `<lightning:inputField fieldName="AccountId" />` field, but the field label is incorrect: it says "Account ID" instead of "Account Name".

[image]

How I can fix it?

Answer (score 2):

From setup, navigate to `Build` -> `Customize` -> `Tab Names and Labels` -> `Rename Tabs and Labels`.

Click edit on Account Standard tabs:

[image]

Then click next to go to fields and there you can find `Account ID', which you can then rename.

[image]

After making changes, probably this would work.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not a case, I have "Account Name" there. I believe it's `lightning:inputField` bug.

Comment: Same issue was also with `apex:inputField` with Account lookup in Visualforce. Give it a try?